# Retrieve multiple key/value pair from single Key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve multiple key/value from my firebase database, it is working fine when One Key has One Value, but when a Key has multiple Key and Value Pairs (check my firebase database - attached) I fail to retrieve it in my app.

[My firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGe5c.jpg)

Note: the 1,2....under the userEmail, userName etc are generated automatically and therefore it is hard for me to understand how to create my class.

Below is the code that I have been trying to figure out.

```
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    User h = dataSnapshot1.getValue(User.class);
                    list.add(h);
            }
            adapter = new User_Adapter(User_Activity.this, list);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

below is my user class

```
public class User {

private String userEmail;
private String userName;
private String userPassword;

public User(){}

public User(String userEmail, String userName, String userPassword) {
    this.userEmail = userEmail;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.userPassword = userPassword;
}

public String getUserEmail() {
    return userEmail;
}

public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    this.userEmail = userEmail;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getUserPassword() {
    return userPassword;
}

public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
    this.userPassword = userPassword;
} }
```

and below is my adapter class

```
public class User_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<User_Adapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
ArrayList<User> users;

public User_Adapter(Context c, ArrayList<User> h){
    context = c;
    users = h;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.user_content,parent,false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.userEmail.setText(users.get(position).getUserEmail());//.setText(users.get(position).getUserEmail());
    holder.userName.setText(users.get(position).getUserName());
    holder.userPassword.setText(users.get(position).getUserPassword());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return users.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView userEmail, userName, userPassword;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        userEmail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.account_recycler);
        userName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.amount_recycler);
        userPassword = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.password_recycler);
    }
} }
```

I require help in understanding how to change my class structure so that the firebase database can be read.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why your data structure like that. Do you want a feature like one user can create many userEmail, userName? 
If you just want to save each user data in database better structure like:

```
Users
  -user1
      userEmail:Imad@test.com
      userName:Imad
      userPassword:123456
  -user2
      userEmail:suhail@test.com
      userName:suhail
      userPassword:123456
```

This also is your user class create for.

Or you want one user can create multiple email.

```
Users
  -userid1
     -pushId1
         userEmail:Imad@test.com
         userName:Imad
         userPassword:123456
     -pushId2
         userEmail:suhail@test.com
         userName:suhail
         userPassword:123456
```

Comment: This structure is correct, and you should use any authentication provider from Firebase to generate unique ID's for each user (or use the push() method to generate random keys for each user if you dont want to sign in each one), so instead of user1 , user2 and so on, you have unique identificators for each one

Comment: so 1 user can have multiple emails and because of this the numbers keep increasing and I have no way of getting them to read in my class. therefore my database structure is like that! any advice??